# Equivalent presentation for the fundamental group of the projective plane

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

We know that $\langle a,b;(ab)^2=1\rangle$ and $\langle z;z^2\rangle$ are presentations of the fundamental group of the projective plane. Therefore, one is obtained from the other via [Tietze transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), but what I get is a contradiction, so I am doing something wrong and I don't know what it is:
$$\langle a,b;(ab)^2=1\rangle\cong\langle a,b,c;(ab)^2=1,c=ab\rangle\cong\langle a,b,c;c^2=1,a=cb^{-1}\rangle
\\\cong\langle b,c;c^2=1\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$$ which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Are you sure $<a,b;(ab)^2>$ is the presentation for the fundamental group of $RP^2$?

Comment: NB that the words $e, a, a^2, a^3, \ldots$ all represent different elements in $\langle a, b ; (ab)^2 = 1 \rangle$.

Comment: Consider the square identifying the edges according the word $abab$. Draw a path connecting the starting points of the $a$ edges  through the diagonal and name this path $c$. If we cut the square through $c$ and paste the remaining triangles identifying the $a$ edges, we get a square identifying the edges according the word $ccb^{-1}b$. Then identifying the $b$ edges we get the 2-polygon of edges $cc$. This is homeomorphic to the projective plane right?

Comment: It is, but the way you're computing the fundamental group is not quite correct. Ignore the 2-cell, and pay attention to what happens with the edges. When you glue them together, you don't get two circles glued together at a point, like with the torus; you get a single circle, with the top hemisphere corresponding to $a$, and the bottom hemisphere corresponding to $b$. This has fundamental group $\langle ab \rangle$. When you glue on your 2-cell, you get fundamental group $\langle ab | (ab)^2 \rangle$. As you noticed here, what the 1-cells are doing before you look at the 2-cell matters a lot!

Comment: I'm more confused now: I know that any identifying polygon (as the previous square) is homeomorphic to a compact, connected 2-manifold, and via cutting and pasting I obtain in every step a homeomorphic space, which at the end is homeomorphic either to a sphere or to a connected sum of some tori or to the connected sum of some projective planes. Now I realize that applying that process to the Klein bottle I obtain the projective plane and not the connected sum of two projective planes. What is happening?

Comment: @MikeMiller $\langle a,b\mid (ab)^2\rangle$ is neither a presentation of the $\pi_1$ of the projective plane, nor of the Klein bottle (the latter is torsion-free). It is not $\pi_1$ of any surface, even with boundary (the only surface with non-torsion-free $\pi_1$ is the projective plane).

Comment: @YCor: I appreciate the correction; I've deleted the offending comment.

Comment: Now I got it! I was assuming that the fundamental group of the identifying square corresponding to the word $abab$ has presentation $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle$ which is totally false. That is the mistake, and  since  $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$, there is no compact, connected 2-manifold with that presentation.
Should I delete this question?

Comment: Au contraire: you should write an answer giving more detail. That way others who have a similar problem can find this later, and you'll be able to write out all the details. Accepting it will take this off the unanswered queue just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of Tietze transformations to prove that $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$ is correct. There are no mistakes in that.

The mistake is to claim that $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle$ is a presentation of the projective plane. In fact, the relation $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$ together with the [Classification of compact 2-manifolds Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_Compact_Two-Manifolds), shows that no compact 2-manifold has a fundamental group with $\langle a,b;(ab)^2\rangle$ as a presentation.

As a side note, the space $X$ obtained from a square by identifying the edges according the word $abab$, is homeomorphic to the projetive plane and we can check this by cutting and pasting as is described in the comments. Therefore the fundamental group of $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
Alternatively, if we use the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem directly in the space $X$, we can choose open subspaces $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $X=U\cup V$, $U\cap V$ is homotopicaly equivalent to $S^1$, $U$ is contractible and $V$ is homotopically equivalent to a circunference identifying antipodal points ("the border of the square $X$"), which is isomorphic to $S^1$. Then we will obtain $\langle (ab),(ab)^2\rangle$ as a presentation of $\pi_1(X)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.